# Wrong input shape when using InceptionResNetV2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

When feeding an image to a pretrained InceptionResNetV2 network, I have the following results.

```py
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2

INPUT_SHAPE = (200, 250, 3)

img = load_img() # loads a 200x250 rgb image into a (200, 250, 3) numpy array
assert img.shape == INPUT_SHAPE # just fine

model = InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE)

model.predict(img)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (200, 150, 3)

I don't understand why and how the model expects a 4 dimension input. What must be done to adapt the (200, 250, 3) image so that it can be processed by the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reshape your input with shapes (1, 200, 150, 3) or (200, 150, 3, 1).

You can use `image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0))` or 
`image = input_data.reshape((-1, image_side1, image_side2, channels))`

Comment: What is the `1` standing for? What values should it take?

Comment: It is probably the number of images per batch. @Jivan

Comment: it's an extra dimension that will not modify your data

Answer (score 1):

You need to feed a batch of images. If your batch has one image, it should also have the same format.

try `img.reshape((1, 200, 150, 3))`